# Request Timeout on Angular Universal server side hosted with heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, request, timeout, angular-universal

I am using Angular Universal (Angular 8, nodejs backend and express server). Everything works fine however I keep getting request timeout errors: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout.

```
Oct 07 11:19:45 example heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/some-url" host=example.com request_id=88c597ae-2c20-4f2b-ac49-fbb757fc2c93 fwd="xx.xx.xx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

How can I find out what is causing these timeouts and how to deal with them?

My express server looks like:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import * as cookieparser from 'cookie-parser';
import {join} from 'path';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.use(cookieparser());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https' && req.hostname !== 'localhost') {
    if (req.url === '/robots.txt') {
      next();
      return;
    }
    res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  }

  if (req.hostname.startsWith('www.')) {
    const host = req.hostname.slice(4, req.hostname.length);
    res.redirect(301, 'https://' + host + req.url);
  }

  next();
}
);

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.headers = res.getHeaders();
  res.render('index', {
    req: req,
    res: res,
    providers: [
      {
        provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: (req)
      },
      {
        provide: 'RESPONSE', useValue: (res)
      }
    ]
  }, (err: Error, html: string) => {
    res.status(html ? 200 : 500).send(html || err.message);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```